# iMessage on Mountain Lion disconnecting AIM and GTalk

Tags: macos, messages

I'm not sure what the cause is, but I never had this issue until I installed Mountain Lion.  I had the iMessage Beta prior to installing Mountain Lion and I did not uninstall it after.  However, I get disconnected constantly and its been going on and off.  I have a lot of difficulty connecting to AIM, but GTalk is disconnecting frequently.  I am not sure where to start.

Comment: This happens to me too. I can usually get around it by going to Preferences > Accounts, and disabling/re-enabling the disconnected accounts.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that, and that USED to work.  I'm out of luck still.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem!  Any solution?

Comment: It's very annoying with people owning both iOS and GTalk... if you want to talk to them on multiple channels, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

I have been having this pesky problem as well.  Mine was solved by reseting the password with the provider.

I found a post that stated that someone solved this by logging into AIM.com website and reseting their password. I tried this and found that since my AIM account was set up through another provider (Apple) that I needed to go to Apple and change my password.  I did this and it resolved my issue.  (I needed to change the Apple password anyway for good security in that I had not changed it in YEARS).

Answer (score 0):

My aim account somehow disappeared from ichat. I had to added it as "other message account" not AOL. Then under preferences->general, I selected "all in one list". Changing the aim password online also helped. Thanks everyone.